# Where are the error messages kept in Magento 1.8?

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Where are the error messages kept in Magento 1.8?

For instance, the error messages on the checkout page,

```
This is a required field. 
Please select a valid credit card type 
Please agree to all the terms and conditions before placing the order. 
Please specify a shipping method.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You will find some of these messages in

```
js/prototype/validation.js
```

while specifically of checkout are in

```
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php
```

as an exception.